# PostgreSQL Circular Index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, circular-reference, circular-list

I have a simple question about: "How to handle with circular index or reference"

The main idea is:
Figure out if you have some data like positions in a string, and you have many strings.

```
String N = {n1 : [start1, end1], n2 : [start2, end2], ..., nn : [startn, endn]}

String A = {a : [1, 10], b : [15, 20], c : [21, 50]}
String B = {a : [52, 8], b : [10, 20], c : [21, 55]}
```

Items within each string might have overlaps and start and end position isn't too important (just to keep items order, e.g `b` came after `a` and before `c`)

I build just another column to assign other to items within each string.

```
String N = {n1 : [start1, end1, index1], n2 : [start2, end2, index2], ..., nn : [startn, endn, indexnn]}

String A = {a : [1, 10, 1], b : [15, 20, 2], c : [21, 50, 3]}
String B = {a : [52, 8, 1], b : [10, 20, 2], c : [21, 55, 3]}
```

The idea is: some times i need to querying assuming the other of the items important, so I do some queries to retrieve all items between 2 forward and 2 backward the query.

Nowadays the query is quiet simple:

```
SELECT * 
FROM strings 
WHERE string = 'A' 
    AND index BETWEEN (
                  SELECT index 
                  FROM strings 
                  WHERE string = 'A' AND item = b
              ) - 1 AND (
                  SELECT index 
                  FROM strings 
                  WHERE string = 'A' AND item = b
              ) + 1;
```

[*or something better than this]
And it will return items `[a, b, c]`

But, how do I retrieve item `a` from `String A` if the query be item `c`?

If I do for item `c`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM strings 
WHERE string = 'A' 
    AND index BETWEEN (
                  SELECT index 
                  FROM strings 
                  WHERE string = 'A' AND item = c
              ) - 1 AND (
                  SELECT index 
                  FROM strings 
                  WHERE string = 'A' AND item = c
              ) + 1;
```

It will not return me `[b, c, a]`, will just return `[b, c]`.

Thanks in advance

EXAMPLE:

Table

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE strings (
     string_name VARCHAR, 
     item VARCHAR, 
     s_start INTEGER, 
     s_end INTEGER, 
     idx INTEGER
);
```

Data

```
INSERT INTO strings VALUES 
('a', 'a1', 10, 20, 1),
('a', 'a2', 10, 20, 2),
('a', 'a3', 10, 20, 3),
('a', 'a4', 10, 20, 4),
('b', 'b1', 1, 20, 1),
('b', 'b2', 10, 20, 2),
('b', 'a3', 10, 20, 3),
('b', 'c4', 10, 20, 4);
```

Common query

```
WITH myvar as (
    SELECT idx as s_idx 
    FROM strings 
    WHERE string_name = 'b' AND item = 'a3'
) 
SELECT * 
FROM strings AS s 
JOIN myvar 
ON true 
WHERE string_name = 'b' 
    AND idx BETWEEN s_idx -1 AND s_idx + 1;
```

output:

```
 string_name | item | s_start | s_end | idx | s_idx  
-------------+------+---------+-------+-----+-------  
 b           | b2   |      10 |    20 |   2 |     3  
 b           | a3   |      10 |    20 |   3 |     3  
 b           | c4   |      10 |    20 |   4 |     3  
(3 rows)
```

Problematic Query (when the `idx` is the higher or lower from string as item `c4` from `String B` which is the last `idx`)

```
WITH myvar as ( 
    SELECT idx as s_idx 
    FROM strings 
    WHERE string_name = 'b' 
         AND item = 'c4'
) 
SELECT * 
FROM strings AS s 
JOIN myvar 
ON true
WHERE string_name = 'b' 
    AND idx BETWEEN s_idx -1 AND s_idx + 1;
```

Output

```
 string_name | item | s_start | s_end | idx | s_idx 
-------------+------+---------+-------+-----+-------
 b           | a3   |      10 |    20 |   3 |     4
 b           | c4   |      10 |    20 |   4 |     4
(2 rows)
```

expected output

```
 string_name | item | s_start | s_end | idx | s_idx 
-------------+------+---------+-------+-----+-------
 b           | a3   |      10 |    20 |   3 |     4
 b           | c4   |      10 |    20 |   4 |     4
 b           | b1   |       1 |    20 |   1 |     4
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your use case. Maybe you could explain it another way? It would be helpful to see your table structure and how data is stored. Please add some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @S-Man thanks, I added a example of table, query, output and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d57fa053d0077c787883dadd301d49f4)

```
WITH myvar as (
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN idx = 1 THEN max_idx ELSE idx - 1 END as prev_idx, -- 2
        idx as s_idx,
        CASE WHEN idx = max_idx THEN 1 ELSE idx + 1 END as next_idx
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            *, 
            MAX(idx) OVER (PARTITION BY string_name) as max_idx      -- 1
        FROM strings 
        WHERE string_name = 'b'
    ) s
    WHERE item = 'c4'
) 
SELECT s.* 
FROM strings AS s 
JOIN myvar 
ON true 
WHERE string_name = 'b' 
    AND idx = ANY (ARRAY[prev_idx, s_idx, next_idx])                 -- 3
```

1. Get the maximum `idx` per string. I got this by using the [window function `MAX`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html)
2. Now I can check whether the previous `idx` should be rolled to the last one (if current `idx` is the first one) or whether the next `idx` should be rolled the first one (if current is last).
3. I didn't use the `BETWEEN` because in your case it results in heavy problems. Because `4,3,1` would result in `BETWEEN 1 AND 4` which would give the `2` too. So I made an array out of these three values, but there are many other ways (subquery instead of CTE e.g.)

---

If you would have greater ranges like [-3, +3] this way could be very nasty. In this case I would try something with modulo:

[demo:db<>dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7e386e68ed922a89de3fd11f09253a7b)

```
WITH myvar as (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            idx as s_idx, 
            item, 
            MAX(idx) OVER (PARTITION BY string_name) + 1 as max_idx
        FROM strings 
        WHERE string_name = 'b'
    )s
    WHERE item = 'g7'
) 
SELECT 
    s.*
FROM strings AS s 
JOIN myvar 
ON true 
WHERE string_name = 'b' 
    AND idx = ANY (ARRAY[
        (s_idx - 3) % max_idx,
        (s_idx - 2) % max_idx,
        (s_idx - 1) % max_idx,
        s_idx,
        (s_idx + 1) % max_idx,
        (s_idx + 2) % max_idx,
        (s_idx + 3) % max_idx
    ])
```

The array part can be also generated with generate_series. So it is more flexible for different ranges:

```
... AND idx IN (
    SELECT (s_idx + gs) % max_idx 
    FROM myvar, generate_series(-3, 3) gs
)
```

Comment: Yes, it help. But the first solution seems restricted just to nearest neighbor item, the second solution seems not flexible, but to the final user the idea is choose how many neighbors item according is necessity, it means, sometime just 1 neighbor, some time 10 neighbors (not allowed to the example).
Thanks.